# Is there more simple way to read irregular data in r?

Tags: r

Here is my data such as the following.The character "." can't be ommitted,it has special meaning.

```
data='编号,学号,性别,民族,籍贯,系部,有无注册学籍,
1,1320207004,男,壮族,广西省,旅游系,有,.,
2,1320207005,女,汉族,重庆市,旅游系,有,,,
3,1320403001,女,汉族,辽宁省,艺术系,有,,,
4,1320403002,女,汉族,广东省,艺术系,有,,,
5,1320403003,女,汉族,四川省,艺术系,有,,,.
6,1320403004,女,汉族,重庆市,艺术系,有,.,,
7,1320403005,男,汉族,海南省,艺术系,有,,,
8,1320403006,男,汉族,海南省,艺术系,有,'
```

You can't read it by :

```
read.table(textConnection(data),sep=",",fill=TRUE,header=TRUE)
```

I read it this way.

```
r <- read.table(textConnection(data),sep=",",fill=TRUE) 
r <- as.matrix(r)
number <- unname(which(apply(r,2,function(y){all(is.na(y))})))
r <- r[,-number] 
header1 <- as.vector(unname(r[1,])) 
r <- r[-1,]
header1 <- header1[header1!=""]
header2 <- paste("v",1:(ncol(r)-length(header1)),sep="")
header <- c(header1,header2)
colnames(r) <- header
noquote(r)


     编号 学号       性别 民族 籍贯   系部   有无注册学籍 v1   v2
[1,] 1    1320207004 男   壮族 广西省 旅游系 有           .      
[2,] 2    1320207005 女   汉族 重庆市 旅游系 有                  
[3,] 3    1320403001 女   汉族 辽宁省 艺术系 有                  
[4,] 4    1320403002 女   汉族 广东省 艺术系 有                  
[5,] 5    1320403003 女   汉族 四川省 艺术系 有                . 
[6,] 6    1320403004 女   汉族 重庆市 艺术系 有           .      
[7,] 7    1320403005 男   汉族 海南省 艺术系 有                  
[8,] 8    1320403006 男   汉族 海南省 艺术系 有
```

Comment: you can run ,the `.` do appear in my result,please try.

Comment: chcp  936 .  please paste your error message here.

Comment: If a particular package is necessary for your code to be reproducible, include the relevant call to `library` or `require`, particularly if the package is somewhat obscure.

Comment: i have delete it  `->` at the end of line.

Comment: I fix it ,you can get the result.

Comment: On my computer `R` converts the symbols to for example `<U+5973>`.  Is there a way I can retain and display the symbols in `R` as you show them?

Comment: in your R,set  the locale into chinese character environment.

Comment: The first 6 commas in your data are the field separators. Then they stop to be them. For example the first row has 8 commas, the last row has 7 commas and the rest have 9. There is no unique way to assign meaning to these inconsistencies, hence you get the error. It is not possible to answer your question how to read this data more efficiently without the information how to interpret these additional commas.

Comment: Here is the line I used to display the symbols as shown above: `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chinese")`  When I closed R and reopened it `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")` revealed that settings were back to their presumed default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
raw <- read.table(textConnection(data),sep=",",fill=TRUE)
dat <- setNames(raw[-1,-9], c(as.character(unlist(raw[1,-c(8:10)])), "v1", "v2"))
```

The result (`dat`):

```
  编号       学号 性别 民族   籍贯   系部 有无注册学籍 v1 v2
2    1 1320207004   男 壮族 广西省 旅游系           有  .   
3    2 1320207005   女 汉族 重庆市 旅游系           有      
4    3 1320403001   女 汉族 辽宁省 艺术系           有      
5    4 1320403002   女 汉族 广东省 艺术系           有      
6    5 1320403003   女 汉族 四川省 艺术系           有     .
7    6 1320403004   女 汉族 重庆市 艺术系           有  .   
8    7 1320403005   男 汉族 海南省 艺术系           有      
9    8 1320403006   男 汉族 海南省 艺术系           有
```